# WOW freezes after login 15.04

Tags: wine, games, freeze, crash

I installed wine 1.6.2 and World of warcraft launcher through it. It fully installed and when I run the game it log ins and asks me to select zone and realm type each time. When I do this the special cursor turns back into a normal cursor and my screen freezes. I can move the mouse and I hear the music, but the screen is frozen. This forces me to reboot the system through ctrl + alt + f2 $ Reboot. I cannot enable opengl because no wtf.config files are made after the game freezes. I wish to play wow on ubuntu and hoping to get some help thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

That helped me with this kind of problem:

```
WINEDEBUG=-all wine "/home/user/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/World of Warcraft/WoW.exe" -noautolaunch64bit
```

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem and the screens only moved when I held down the windows key and then refroze. after a lot of trial and error. I finally found a solution. it seems to come down to screen refresh rate and windows/graphics card refresh / framerate being out of sync. once I set all to same rate (60hz and fps cap of 70fps game worked fine. resolution of 1920x1080.
to find the refresh rate for my screen I went to windows advanced settings and the monitor tab, there it lists the refresh rates your screen can use.